How can I find the link of a button with hidden link?
Please observe this link (related to a sandbox report):
https://cuckoo.cert.ee/analysis/5408154/export/
On this page, there is a button to download the report, but we don't have access to the direct link. In fact, if you right-click on the button, you won't see any link.
I want to write a script to download thousands of such reports, as manually downloading them is very difficult. Is there any way to find the direct link to the report?

This is not a place to ask broad questions about how a web application work. I think that learning about web scraping tools and methods might help you to reach your goal. ,[su], [so] and [softwarerecs.se] are some of the sites that handle questions related to web scraping
